# How do I allow brackets in a php preg_match function call?

Tags: php, preg-match

I want to allow brackets in my php preg_match function call:

```
preg_match("/[^A-Za-z0-9-_,#@. \/']/",$address).
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
preg_match("/[^A-Za-z0-9-_,#@. \/\(\)']/", $address).
```

Answer (score 3):

You should escape the brackets with a backslash:

```
preg_match("/[^A-Za-z0-9-_,#@. \/'\[\]]/",$address);
```

Comment: @Jan-Henk when i use this preg_match then show error "Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier ''' in mycontroller.php"

Comment: The / in your original code was not escaped with a backslash, that is why you got the error message. I edited my answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
 preg_match("/[^A-Za-z0-9-_,#@. /'\[\]]/",$address)
```